# Patterns for making two packages as loosely coupled as possible

Tags: java, design-patterns, lexical-analysis

So I'm learning to build a parser for a intro class for software design.

I have built a tokenizer package that splits my input string into Token objects that have getters for both the value and type. I can also return a raw String for value and type of the current token.

My public facing interface from the Tokenizer currently looks like this.

```java
public Tokenizer(Grammar rules, String input)
public Token getCurrentToken() {...} // Token has public getters similar to the two methods below
public String getCurrentValue() {...}
public String getCurrentType() {...}
public void nextToken() throws InvalidTokenException {...}
public void previousToken() {...}
```

In my Parser class I also have a TokenReceiver(interface) and a TokenizerAdapter class (implements Receiver and my specific tokenizer)

```java
  public void next();
  public Token getToken();
  public String getType();
  public String getValue();
  public Token getToken();
}
```

The rules are that each of the different steps in the parsing has to be done with different packages that are as loosely coupled as possible to any implementation details of the other packages, i.e. the parser should in theory work with **any** tokenizer I find(for example on Github), not just my own Tokenizer implementation, provided I just make an Adapter for it.

If I send back the Token objects from the Tokenizer then my parser will have to know about the Token objects (the getter methods specifically), which adds coupling to my Tokenizer implementation.

Sending back straight Strings for the value and type and then creating a another Token class in the Parser package and recreating Tokens objects feels instinctively wrong to me. Could an anonymous inner class for Token in the adapter class be a good solution?

I'm looking for what kind of patterns or concepts that can help me reference my Tokens from the Tokenizer while preserving a loose coupling to my specific tokenizer implementation.

Sorry if question is really stupid and the answer is really obvious, design patterns are still very abstract to me and we're learning about so many of them I have a hard time knowing which one to use for different circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the following

```
public interface Token {
   String getType();
   String getValue();
}

public interface Tokenizer {
   // either 
   Iterable<Token> parse(String input);

   // or
   Stream<Token> parse(String input);
}

public class GrammarTokenizer implements Tokenizer {
   private final Grammar grammar;

   // constructor 

   // method implementations 
}
```

Comment: No, adding this to the Tokenizer or Parser package?

Comment: It doesn't matter which package they are in. Using this approach you can get rid of all the `nextToken()` `currentValue()` methods from your custom classes since `Iterable` and/or `Stream` provide this

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful answer :)

Comment: Note: Using my approach, your Tokenizer can be immutable / thread-safe and reusable for multiple inputs

Answer (score 1):

Implementing interfaces might help when you want to pass some objects between classes while trying to avoid tight coupling between the classes. In your case, maybe create a Token Interface and reference that interface from your tokenizers and parsers instead of directly referencing the concrete Token Class (the Token Class should implement the Token Interface).